# TagBundle: Elements with the same Tag

Tags: sulu

There is the TagBundle in SuluCMF included.
I know how I get the Tags for a given item.

How can i get relates articles for this item in SuluCMF the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you exactly understand under related articles. A simple solution would be to use the [SmartContent](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/creating-a-basic-website/using-smart-content.html?highlight=smartcontent). Then the content manager can use the smart content to filter the pages by tags.

Another solution would be to use the internal links content type, so the content manager can choose manually which pages are related. This will of course be more work for the content manager, but the results would be the most accurate.

If you really want to filter based on the tags you assigned to the page, which should show the related elements, then you have to implement something on your own, since we are not supporting something like that out of the box. The `DocumentManager::createQuery` method might be useful for that.

Comment: Yeah, i testes the first two solutions on my own. The second one is my prefered one, but the content manager did not want this.

So I'm going with a custom query for now. (because the content managers are "damn stupid"), they will crash the SmartContent :-D

I just did not want to reimplement somithing that might be hidden somewere in there already. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a nice feature IMO. Maybe one day :-)